# Cronjobs do not execute although present in syslog

Tags: unix, cron

I've configured some tasks in root crontab like :

```
1 * * * * zcat -f /var/log/apache2/custom.site1.log.* | goaccess --log-format COMMON -o /var/www/site1/reports/index.html
2 * * * * zcat -f /var/log/apache2/error.site1.log.* | goaccess --log-format='[%^ %d %t.%^ %^] [%^] [%^] [%^ %h:%^] %^: %U, %^: %R' --time-format=%T --date-format='%b %d' --http-protocol=no --http-method=no -o /var/www/site1/reports/errors.html
```

With a `cat /var/log/syslog | grep CRON`, I see that it's started every hour like it should :

```
Jan 29 12:05:01 sd-102290 CRON[21454]: (root) CMD (zcat -f /var/log/apache2/error.site1.log.* | goaccess --log-format='[)
Jan 29 12:05:01 sd-102290 CRON[21465]: (root) CMD (zcat -f /var/log/apache2/custom.site1.log.* | goaccess --log-format COMMON -o /var/www/site1/reports/index.html)
```

But it doesn't work. The command works like a charm when executed from command line. 
I don't know where I could look from errors coming from this cron.

Moreover, I see that my command seems truncated in the syslog (it stops at `goaccess --log-format='[`)

Thanks

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue at hand is that the command you wish to execute contains the `%` character. According to the crontab manual, a `%` is considered to be the end of the command and everything after the `%` is standard input for the command. If your command requires a `%` such as general format strings of `printf` or `date`, you need to escape the `%`.

> **`man 5 crontab`**
>
> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or
>   a "`%`" character, will be executed by `/bin/sh` or by the shell specified in the `SHELL` variable of the cronfile.  A "`%`" character in the command, unless escaped with a backslash (`\`), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first `%` will be sent to the command as standard input.

So if you have a command of the type :

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
read foo
echo $foo
```

and the crontab reads :

```
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *   command to be executed
  1  *  *  *  *   cmd > ~/foo % hello world
  1  *  *  *  *   printf "hello \%s\n" universe > ~/bar
```

The file `~/foo` will contain the content `hello world` and `~/bar` will contain `hello universe` (and not `hello \universe`).

Comment: Thanks, my command line is now correct in the syslog.
Sadly, it doesn't correct the fact that my command doesn't seem executed where it's correct when executed directly in CLI.

Comment: @kzrdt `cron` runs your command in a [restricted environment](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)  It is likely that you have to adjust your `PATH` or write down the full path of `zcat` and `goaccess` as `/path/to/zcat` and `/other/path/to/goaccess`. Nonetheless I would suggest to copy your lines in 2 scripts and execute the scripts from the cron.

Comment: it works perfectly in a bash script. Thanks for your help.